# Java practice assignment confusion about a test case failing

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a coding problem on a site called coding bat and can't figure out why one of the tests fails.

-Problem 
"Given an array of ints, return true if .. 1, 2, 3, .. appears in the array somewhere."

http://codingbat.com/prob/p136041

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
  boolean result = false;
  for(int i=0; i < nums.length-2; i++){
    if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i+1] == 2 && nums[i+2] == 3){
      result = true;
    } else{ result = false;}
  }
  return result;
}
```

All tests pass except for this:
       `array123({1, 1, 2, 3, 1}) → true` but my code is actually returning `false`. Why?

Comment: you overwrite the result. the last check is: 2, 3, 1, so it will be set to false.

Comment: you want the sequence 1,2,3 or 1,2 and 3 appearing anywhere seperately?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return your result, or break out of the loop when you get a positive result. You've gotten other answers using return. Here's a version with the return statement at the end:

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
    boolean result = false;
    for(int i=0; i < nums.length-2; i++){
        if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i+1] == 2 && nums[i+2] == 3){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You're code fails because `result` is set correctly to `true` on the next to last iteration, but back to `false` on the last iteration. If you didn't care about optimization you could also simply just delete the else part of your if-statement.

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
    boolean result = false;
    for(int i=0; i < nums.length-2; i++){
        if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i+1] == 2 && nums[i+2] == 3){
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If it ever comes across your sequence then it sets `result` to `true`, and it will never be able to go back to `false`. Although you will be running to the end of the number series - not optimal.

Comment: Great explanation especially regarding treatment of optimization. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You should return true immediately when you find one occurrence of the sequence.

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0; i < nums.length-2; i++){
    if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i+1] == 2 && nums[i+2] == 3)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Why? the way I'm doing it does turn it in to true. The else should never run

Comment: @TazMan The else may get executed in a subsequent for loop iteration. It will make the value of result to false again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the else statement, you already initialize result to false. Here is the code after the fix.

```
public boolean array123(int[] nums) {
  for(int i=0; i < nums.length-2; i++){
    if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i+1] == 2 && nums[i+2] == 3){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     boolean result = false;
      for(int i=0; i <= nums.length-2; i++){
         if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i+1] == 2 && nums[i+2] == 3)
         result = true;
     }
```

Only this will suffice. You've an else statement placed wrongly. On finding 1,2,3 it sets ***result=true*** but then it moves to 2,3,1 and there it goes in else and sets ***result=false*** again.